# gdbserver ptrace warning slowing down debugging?

Tags: gdb, ptrace, gdbserver

I'm trying to remotely debug my application using gdbserver but the process seems to be extremely slow.
The output of gdbserver is full of the following lines:

```
ptrace(regsets_fetch_inferior_registers) PID=4474: No data available
Warning: ptrace(regsets_store_inferior_registers): No data available
```

Not sure if the warnings and the slowness are related, but would appreciate anything that would help with understanding the root cause and fixing the warnings anyway.

As an additional note, gdbserver is running on an ARM box, and I'm using gdb-multiarch to connect to it from an x86_64.

Thanks!